# Equality in distribution with vector

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $~\overset d=~$ denotes equality in distribution, does
$$X_i\overset d= Y_i,\text{ for $i=1,\dots,n$}$$
imply
$$(X_1,\dots,X_n)\underset ?{\overset d=}(Y_1,\dots,Y_n)$$

Are there certain requirements for this relation or is it completely wrong/always right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: define $X_1=X$, $Y_1=X$, $X_2=X$ and $Y_2=-X$ where $X$ is a symmetric Bernoulli random variable, then $X_1\stackrel{d}{=}Y_1$ and $X_2\stackrel{d}{=}Y_2$, but $(X_1,X_2)\stackrel{d}{=}(Y_1,Y_2)$ cannot hold since $P(X_1=X_2)=1$ while $P(Y_1=Y_2)=0$.

Comment: What if we add to the requirements that the $X_i$ are not equal (in distribution) to each other?

Comment: Big deal... show us that it does not change a thing.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thanks for the answers.